# Is caching good when frequently accessing the property of an object's property?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, properties

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var k;
for(k in obj){
    if(obj.p1.p1.p1){
        obj.p1.p1.p2 = obj.p1.p1.p3;
    }
    // ...
    // more stuff with obj.p1.p1
    // ...
}
```

Will it work better if I were to store `obj.p1.p1` in a variable like this?

```
var k, p;
for(k in obj){
    p = obj.p1.p1;
    if(p.p1){
        p.p2 = p.p3;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This way I'm making less property accessing, but I'm using more memory (I have one more variable).

Which is the better way? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, from a strict performance standpoint,<sup>1</sup> it would be faster to save the value to a variable and use the variable.

In practice, assuming the JavaScript engine knows other threads cannot modify that value (that's true on browsers and NodeJS, for instance), if it becomes performance-critical, a decent modern JavaScript engine will do it for you where possible. The degree of analysis done may vary engine to engine, but they're pretty much all *really fast* now.

Whether it's "better" from a style or maintenance point of view is a matter of opinion, and so off-topic for SO.

---

<sup>1</sup> **However**: Even if it's faster, it's unlikely to actually matter, and so worrying about it from a performance perspective is likely to be premature micro-optimization. Write what you believe to be the clearest code, and worry about which is faster if/when you have a specific performance problem to solve.

Comment: The reason I asked is because i often have to modify properties of properties that have overall length of 25-35 characters. That's annoying. But basically I'll be completely alright if I use variables to store this stuff, right?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov: I don't know that I understand that question.

Comment: Using variables for object properties to improve code readability won't cause major differences in overall feel and performance?

Comment: @HristiyanDodov: No, not at all. Or even a minor one. ;-)